# Can't browse VB.NET web site on Azure from external browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, azure, iis

I get "the webpage cannot be found (HTTP 404 Not Found)".

I can browse it from Azure > IIS8 Manager > Connections > my server > Sites > my web URL > right-click > Manage Website > browse
but not from my local office desktop.

Azure browser cannot browse it either.
Azure http://localhost/  doesn't work

UPDATE 8/3/2016:
All above problems occur on Internet Explorer on my Azure Windows VM, or on my home office desktop Windows 7.
From home office, Chrome and Safari work ok!
IE fails at home office or Azure.

VB.NET web site is deployed as IIS virtual directory to directory of web site project.  No cloud service (other than Azure VM for Windows Server 2012 R2)
VS 2015 Community.

UPDATE:
Chrome browses site ok from external.   Internet Explorer 11 doesn't browse the web site.
Have been using IE for the web site for years.

Now it doesn't work.

Comment: How did you deploy to Azure: Web App? Virtual Machine? Cloud Service? What do you mean you can browse it from Azure -> IIS8 -> Sites? Are you referring to a VM in Azure? As for Azure `http://localhost` - are you RDP'd into a VM and trying to get to localhost? As for accessing from external browser: Did you open endpoints (or set up inbound security rules)? As it stands, your question doesn't really make sense and will likely be closed as *Unclear what you're asking*. Please edit your question to contain more details and clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem by using Chrome instead of Internet Explorer 11.
(IE11 had been working for the last year.)

Answer (score 0):

Check some:

1. Register .net to iis like this:
   in cmd: aspnet_regiis -i

2.check framework on iis in application pool if the same with your framework using
  in framework option.

3.make sure it is enabled

[image]